# How to convert DynamicImage to Base64?

Tags: image-processing, rust, base64

I can convert a Base64 string to a `DynamicImage` using the `image` and `base64` crates but I can not convert the image back to a Base64 string.

What I am doing wrong here? How to achieve this?

```
extern crate base64;
extern crate image;

fn main() {
    /*
    Base64 to image
        let img_buffer = base64::decode("qwerty...").unwrap();
        let mut base_img = image::load_from_memory(img_buffer.as_slice()).unwrap();

    */

    let mut base_img = image::open("player.png").unwrap();

    base_img.invert();

    // base_img.save("player1.png").unwrap();

    // image to Base64
    let res_base64 = base64::encode(base_img.raw_pixels().as_slice());

    println!("{}", res_base64)
}
```

Base64 value of original image

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAYAAAD0eNT6AAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAgAElEQVR42uydd5hlRZn/v1Un3dzdt/P0pJ6enANxGKISFEQkg4ur6667uquuCiKCIJKUpAj7U3cN66orWVERVxBmmDxMYHLOM90znfvGk6rq98e9ICoo0Kf73u5+P8+DjPBwZrpO1Xm...
```

Base64 value of Gimp inverted image

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAYAAAD0eNT6AAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAB3RJTUUH4wgMCCwxQF4N2QAAIABJREFUeNrsvXmc3FWZ7...
```

The response I am getting not the proper Base64 value:

```
////AP///wD///8A////AP///wD///8A////AP///wD///8A////AP///wD///8A////AP///wD///8A////AP///wD///8A////AP///wD///...
```

Comment: What happens when you try running that code? If it doesn't compile or if it fails to run, paste the complete error message in your question. If it runs but gives a "wrong" result, tell us what the actual and expected results are so we can understand what's going on.

Comment: I have added more details, please check. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Base64 values of the original and Gimp images represent PNG-encoded images. The response you're getting represents raw pixel data. You will need to convert the data to PNG before encoding as Base64. This should do it:

```
let mut buf = vec![[]];
base_img.write_to(&mut buf, image::ImageOutputFormat::PNG);
let res_base64 = base64::encode(&buf);
```

Comment: It was expecting a typed vector vec![], after that it's working perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer for a base64 encoded image for webbrowsers.

My 2022 solution is:

```ini
#Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
base64 = "0.13"
image = "0.24"
```

```rust
use image::{DynamicImage, ImageOutputFormat};
use std::io::Cursor;

fn image_to_base64(img: &DynamicImage) -> String {
    let mut image_data: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    img.write_to(&mut Cursor::new(&mut image_data), ImageOutputFormat::Png)
        .unwrap();
    let res_base64 = base64::encode(image_data);
    format!("data:image/png;base64,{}", res_base64)
}

let img = image::load_from_memory(&data.clone()).unwrap();
println!("{}", image_to_base64(&img));
```

You can use this string for html tag <img src="..." />.

Updated 2023 solution:

```ini
#Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
base64 = "0.21.5"
image = "0.24.7"
```

```rust
use base64::{engine::general_purpose, Engine as _};
use image::{DynamicImage, ImageOutputFormat};
use std::io::Cursor;

fn image_to_base64(img: &DynamicImage) -> String {
    let mut image_data: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    img.write_to(&mut Cursor::new(&mut image_data), ImageOutputFormat::Png)
        .unwrap();
    let res_base64 = general_purpose::STANDARD.encode(image_data);
    format!("data:image/png;base64,{}", res_base64)
}

let img = image::load_from_memory(&data.clone()).unwrap();
println!("{}", image_to_base64(&img));
```

Comment: Might be nice to explain that the `data:image/png;base64` part is only needed in web contexts (like in an img tag as you've mentioned).