# Send a DynamicImage as a response with axum

Tags: image, rest, rust, rust-axum

I tried to send a PNG as `GET`-response to a client with axum. For this I load an image into a `DynamicImage` from the [image](https://docs.rs/image/latest/image/) crate. When I send a request from my browser, no image is shown. In firefox I get the message:

> The image "http://<the-URL-of-the-GET-request>" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

In my terminal is no error message.

The reason I put the image in an `DynamicImage` object in my example is because I want to generate images on request and then reply to the client.

---

### What I've tried

First, I created an API, where I can get the image following the instructions in the [axum](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/) documentation.

```rust
let app = Router::new().route("/image", get(get_image)).with_state(());
axum::Server::bind(&"0.0.0.0:3000".parse().unwrap())
    .serve(app.into_make_service())
    .await
    .unwrap();
}
```

The function `get_image()` loads the PNG-file, put it in an `DynamicImage` from the [image](https://docs.rs/image/latest/image/) crate. Next, I try to send the bytes back to the client.

```rust
pub async fn get_image() -> impl axum::response::IntoResponse {
    let img_path = PathBuf::from("<path/to/image>").join("ferris.png");
    let image = image::io::Reader::open(&img_path).unwrap().decode().unwrap();

    (
        axum::response::AppendHeaders([(header::CONTENT_TYPE, "image/png")]),
        image.into_bytes()
    )
}
```

For this, I adapted the code from [here](https://github.com/joelparkerhenderson/demo-rust-axum/blob/main/README.md#respond-with-a-custom-header-and-image). But I tried to load the image from hard drive and not, as in the example shown, from *base64* string.

I also converted the image to a *base64* string and sent this back as shown in the [example](https://github.com/joelparkerhenderson/demo-rust-axum/blob/main/README.md#respond-with-a-custom-header-and-image). This worked fine. However, I don't want to convert the image into a string every time, only to be able to send it again as a byte stream. Is there any direct way that I am overlooking?

---

Comment: If you tell the browser that you're sending an `image/png`, then you need to actually send a PNG image, but here you're sending raw data.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/57457818/5397009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting the raw bitmap (your `DynamicImage`) into bytes, you must encode it to adhere to the PNG format.

Something like this should work to convert the raw image to PNG and write the PNG to a a byte buffer that you can serve with axum:

```rust
use image::ImageFormat;

use std::io::{BufWriter, Cursor};

let mut buffer = BufWriter::new(Cursor::new(Vec::new()));
image.write_to(&mut buffer, ImageFormat::Png).unwrap();
    
let bytes: Vec<u8> = buffer.into_inner().unwrap().into_inner();
```

Comment: This is the missing link I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the image crate if you only want to send a static file.
[`Image::into_bytes`](https://docs.rs/image/latest/image/enum.DynamicImage.html#method.into_bytes) will return the raw pixels from the image.

To serve the file, you can use [`tower_http::services::ServeFile`](https://docs.rs/tower-http/latest/tower_http/services/struct.ServeFile.html). You can also look at the [`static-file-server` example](https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/blob/main/examples/static-file-server/src/main.rs).